# Where to install Oracle client software on SharePoint 2010 Server

Tags: oracle, sharepoint

We have our ASP.net web application hosted on a SharePoint Server 2010. Our application uses oracle database to save and retrieve data.For our application to work on SharePoint server we need to install Oracle client software.

Our SharePoint Server architecture consists as following

- 2 web front ends
- Index Server
- Crawl Server
- Application server
- Load Balancer.

I am not the admin on the SharePoint server and trying to figure out if i have to install Oracle client on server where do i install it? Do i need to install it on all our servers or just the web fronends. Can some one please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about Sharepoint but in usual cases Oracle client has to be installed into server where application which connects to Oracle is located. So if your application will be running on Application server you should install Oracle client here.
Just for the information you can also try [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). It uses less disk space and you do not have to install it. Just unpack where you prefer and point TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the directory where you unpacked it.
You can find variables by right clicking Computer icon then select Properties, Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables. And then add TNS_ADMIN to system variables.